# How to correctly export VDB files from Blender smoke or cloud generator?

Tags: particles, smoke-simulation

[image: Point density to VDB?]

Hi, I´m trying to export a simple Cloud generator simulation to VDB. I know it´s a point density texture, I just want to know if its possible or not.

The way I would normally do this on Modo is to create a particle simulation, cache it and then export it as VDB.

How do I correctly export a .VDB simulation, say to Houdini or Modo?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In Blender 2.81 the "VOLUME" object data was introduced in Blender. The way it works is: SHIFT+A > Add a volume object, and go to the properties of the volume, and target a vdb sequence by selecting all of its files in the explorer window, then ACCEPT.
You can playback the result in the timeline, which will "cache" to view it on GRID voxels. You can setup a principled volume shader to also tweak temperature and combustion plus other attributes you sent from your original vdb export software into Blender.

2.79 which is the version this question was asked, DID NOT had any vdb addons ready for the public at the time. All though Tangent Animation Studios did implement their first vdb reader as a custom in-house solution to develop the Netflix movie NEXT GEN back in 2.78.